# Getting googlemap traffic data (estimated duration)

Tags: google-maps

I was wondering if it is possible to get the ETA data derived from traffic conditions that google maps produces.

Basically when I run googlemaps I get a duration approximation 'traffic free' and another that considers traffic conditions.

Does the Gdirection.getduration () method return non-traffic ETA or traffic modified ETA?

If the former is there some other way to proceed to get that traffic data?

I know in '09 someone asked a similar question but had no answers so I was hoping someone might know better by now.

Any help is very appreciated.
JF

Answer (score 3):

Not currently. This is only supported on maps.google.com, not via the API. See [Issue 2221](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2221) on the Maps API issue tracker.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way to scan the webpage code with a bot and gather the data that way and if so would that even be legal? I tried to seek google staff for answers surrounding this but they have yet to reply.

Comment: Definitely against the terms of service.